# How can I add a warning before I turn off my computer?

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop, shutdown

I want to use TeamViewer on my work PC to work from home when I need to. Being a creature of habit I'm afraid i'll click the shutdown button on the friday before the week-end when I need it the most...

How could I add a warning with a friendly reminder to confirm the shutdown possibly with a message saying "Hey are you sure you won't need to access this computer?"

I cannot make my work PC Wake On LAN so it would *have* to stay on.

System: **Windows 7 Pro 64-bit**

PS: I'll take advice on other remote desktop solutions

Comment: Use a scheduled task that runs a simple program

Comment: Thanks, I'm now looking at Windows Task Scheduler but I can't find the shutdown event. Note that I am now at home on Windows 8.1 (and both my PCs are French). Do you have any specific pointer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [Shutdown Event Tracker](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc732119.aspx) for this. It will stop you from shutting down or restarting the computer without providing a reason.

Overkill? You decide.

Comment: Good idea. That's actually what we use on our Windows Server 2008... I'll check this out.

Comment: Reason for shutdown? "I don't want to do any work this weekend."

Comment: I just tried this and it works on my Windows 8.1. Thanks a lot!

Comment: This would usually require the Group Policy Editor (`gpedit.msc`), which is only available in Professional and higher editions. As a workaround, open a command prompt with admin rights, and run the following command: `reg add "HKLM\Software\Policies\Microsoft\Windows NT\Reliability" /v "ShutdownReasonUI" /t REG_DWORD /d 1 /f`. Changes are applied immediately.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the *Local Group Policy Editor* to remove the options to power off, restart etc. from the start menu.

Note: This only works with the Professional or Ultimate edition of Win7, not with Home, and requires local admin privileges.

The steps are:

- run `gpedit.msc`
- under `User Configuration / Administrative Templates / Start Menu and Taskbar` there is a setting to remove access to the shutdown commands

There is a [detailed explanation on howtogeek.com](http://www.howtogeek.com/howto/7553/remove-shutdown-and-restart-buttons-in-windows-7/).

Comment: Thanks, but that seems a bit too drastic. I'd like to still have the option to shutdown the usual way, just with an extra step.

Comment: You could still shutdown with the power button.

Comment: I never go to the shutdown option - I just run the command shutdown -s -t 1 when I want to shutdown.  Or shutdown -r -t 1 when I want to reboot from an admin level command prompt.  You COULD create a shortcut to that too.  Or increase the time delay from 1 second (-t 1) to something like -t 300 (5 minutes) so if you realize you shutdown the wrong system, you can cancel the shutdown with shutdown  -a